# Unnecessary characters are included in regular expression url conversion

Tags: ruby, regex

I check the url with regular expressions.

Process the url contained in the body to html.

Unnecessary charcters get in, so I do not want to include unnecessary charcters.

My regular expressions is as follows.

```
body
=> "https://www.yahoo.com/<br /><br />sample<br /><br/>https://www.yahoo.com/"
url
=>"https://www.yahoo.com/"
text
=> "<!-- BEGIN app/views/topics/_link_thumbnail_description.html.slim -->\n\n<a class=\"c-grid__quotation--link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.yahoo.com/\"><div class=\"c-grid__quotation text--s-md p-topic__quotation__border c-border-r-5\">\n  <div class=\"c-flex\">\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--main\">\n      <img src=\"https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/130909/y_200_a.png\" alt=\"Y 200 a\" />\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side\">\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-title text--b\">\n        Yahoo\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-description\">\n        News, email and search are just the beginning. Discover more every day. Find your yodel.\n      </div>\n      <div class=\"c-grid__quotation--side-url\">\n        www.yahoo.com\n      </div>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</div></a><!-- END app/views/topics/_link_thumbnail_description.html.slim -->"


  def convert_url_to_text(body, url, text)
    reg_url = Regexp.escape("#{url}")
    body.gsub!(/(#{reg_url}$|#{reg_url}[\W\/])/){ |s| "#{text}"}
  end
```

it becomes a state of regular expression.

```
/(https:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com\/$|https:\/\/www\.yahoo\.com\/[\W\/])/
```

But url will get < int the body

http://rubular.com/

How can I make not < not contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do parsing manually. Use [`URI#extract`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract):

```
URI.extract "https://www.yahoo.com/<br />
   <br />sample<br /><br/>https://www.yahoo.com/"
#⇒ ["https://www.yahoo.com/", "https://www.yahoo.com/"]
```